# how do I center floated left nav tabs in wrapper?

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I have a footer with nav tabs. I am trying to center the tabs that are inside of a wrapper that is 960px with a padding of 20 left and right. The tabs are inside of a wrapper and they are floated left. The only way I can seem to center them is put a width on the nav wrapper, however it's not purely centered.

this is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Here is the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="footer_nav clear">
            <a href="">
                <div class="nav_tab">
                    Home
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="nav_tab">&#124;</div>
            <a href="">
                <div class="nav_tab">
                    About Us
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="nav_tab">&#124;</div>
            <a href="">
                <div class="nav_tab">
                    Portfolio
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="nav_tab">&#124;</div>
            <a href="">
                <div class="nav_tab">
                    Contact Us
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            Copyright 2013 Lanai Construction. License #579449
        </div>
        <div class="social_wrapper_footer">
            <div class="fb">
            </div>
            <div class="t">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css:

```
.footer_nav {
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
 margin-top:40px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 vertical-align:center;
}
.nav_tab {
 font-family:'Edmon';
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:left;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 margin-right:10px;
}
```

this is all inside of a wrapper that 960 plus 20px left and right

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `.nav_tab`, try `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

Comment: does the same thing that float left is doing

Comment: when I don't use display:inline-block or float left, the tabs are centered but stacked vertically.

Comment: do as @Michelle said and add `text-align: center` to your `.wrapper`